# "AccessToken.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out oAuth2 token based authentication since 3 days and no avail yet. I have written a code for user authentication. However, I am getting an error of

> ValueError at /api/customer/login/ Cannot assign "{'username':
>   'sanskars'}": "AccessToken.user" must be a "User" instance.

What might be the soultion for this? And why the following error is raised?

**views.py**

```
class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        access_token = request.GET.get('access_token')
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            if new_data:
                app = Application.objects.get(name="appname")
                try:
                    print('trying to fetch old token if exists')
                    old_token = AccessToken.objects.get(user=new_data, appliction=app)
                    print('old_token',old_token)
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    old_token.delete()
                new_token = generate_token()
                print('new_token',new_token)
                AccessToken.objects.create(user=new_data, application=app, expires=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365),token=new_token)
                print('aceess',AccessToken)
            return Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField()
    # email = EmailField(label='Email Address')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',

        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{"write_only": True} }
```

Also one confusion is there do i need to generate token while registering user?

Comment: I created an instance of user this way user = User.objects.get(username=new_data['username']) and then passed that user instance in AccessToken. It worked. what else i have to do now ?